# creating a shuffle method for playlist in java

Tags: java, arrays, random

Although the instructions below seem to be clear, I am utterly confused on how to implement this code.

One of the most popular features of contemporary music software is the ability to randomize the order of the songs in a playlist—an action called “shuffling” the songs. Create a shuffle method using the below pseudo code as a guide:

```
create a new empty arraylist (called newList)

while (there are still songs left)

randomly select the index of one song on the playlist

remove it from the current playlist and place it at the end of newList

songs = newList
```

Hint: Generate a random number using the Random class in the Java library. Its method is: 
public int nextInt(int n).
This returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value as low as 0 and as high as n. Therefore, nextInt(songs.size()) gives you a random index. Remember that the size of songs lessens by one each time you add a randomly selected song to newList. You will need to account for this each time you generate a random number.

This is what I have which causes the program to crash. I need help with retrieving a song from the array, removing it, and placing it in a new array list. PLEASE HELP ME!

```
public int nextInt(int n) {

int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(songs.size());
              return index;
 }
public void shuffle (){
    newList = new ArrayList<Mp3> ();
    while (songs.size()>0){
        Mp3 song = songs.get(nextInt(songs.size()));
        newList.add(song);
        System.out.println("new list" + newList);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why not simply use Collections.shuffle(list), which shuffles the list for you, and then iterate through this shuffled list? That said, you need two lists: the original, initially full list, from which you'll pick and remove a song randomly at each iteration, and an initially empty list, that you'll fill with the songs picked randomly from the first one. You forgot to remove the picked song in your code.

Comment: @JBNizet You only need one list because the "second" list would be the same order as you played the first. Or you keep one list and re-shuffle it each time.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track there, but you forgot to implement one step of the description:

```
remove it from the current playlist and place it at the end of newList
```

The method Shuffle needs to be rewritten to the following:

```
public void shuffle (){
    newList = new ArrayList<Mp3> ();
    while (songs.size()>0){
        Mp3 song = songs.get(nextInt(songs.size()));
        songs.remove(song); // the forgotten step
        newList.add(song);
        System.out.println("new list" + newList);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SuffleSongs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> playList = new ArrayList<String>();
        playList.add("Song1");
        playList.add("Song2");
        playList.add("Song3");
        playList.add("Song4");
        playList.add("Song5");
        playList.add("Song6");
        playList.add("Song7");
        playList.add("Song8");
        playList.add("Song9");
        playList.add("Song10");
        playList.add("Song11");
        playList.add("Song12");
        playList.add("Song13");
        playList.add("Song14");
        playList.add("Song15");
        playList.add("Song16");
        playList.add("Song17");
        playList.add("Song18");
        playList.add("Song19");
        playList.add("Song20");
        playList.add("Song21");

        // shuffle the playlist
        for (int i=0; i<playList.size(); ++i) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int temp = rand.nextInt(playList.size() -i) + i;
            Collections.swap(playList, i, temp);
        }

        // print the shuffled playlist
        for(int j = 0; j < playList.size(); ++j) {
            System.out.println(playList.get(j));
        }

    }

}
```

This will shuffle without need of creating new playlist (ArrayList). 
Basically this code just gets a playlist ArrayList and then shuffle within the same ArrayList.

Comment: The instructions say: "randomly select the index of one song on the playlist, remove it from the current playlist and place it at the end of newList"

Comment: @zac the loop can be run in reverse order. I believe the code can still be used for reference.

Comment: The order of the loop does not change that fact that this is a "swap n times" but the algorithm requested it to build a array by moving each item at random. It is very likely that items in your algorithm will remain in their initial positions.

Answer (score 0):

The program goes crash, it is because, in your `shuffle` method,  **`while (songs.size()>0){`** is always be `true`. **The size of list is not changed.**

If you want to write a `shuffle` method with your own, then a simple way is to **iterater the songs list** and **swap 2 songs of current index i and the song with a random index**.

```
     public void shuffle (List<Mp3> songsList)
     {
         for(int i=0;i< songsList.size(); i++)
         {
             //Do something here
                              //generate a random number
             //Swap songs according to the i index and and random index.
         }
     }
```

The simpliest way is to use **Collections # shuffle** method to make the list to be random.

Corresponding source code of shuffle in Collections is as follows:

```
/**
 * Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of
 * randomness.  All permutations occur with approximately equal
 * likelihood.<p>
 *
 * The hedge "approximately" is used in the foregoing description because
 * default source of randomness is only approximately an unbiased source
 * of independently chosen bits. If it were a perfect source of randomly
 * chosen bits, then the algorithm would choose permutations with perfect
 * uniformity.<p>
 *
 * This implementation traverses the list backwards, from the last element
 * up to the second, repeatedly swapping a randomly selected element into
 * the "current position".  Elements are randomly selected from the
 * portion of the list that runs from the first element to the current
 * position, inclusive.<p>
 *
 * This method runs in linear time.  If the specified list does not
 * implement the {@link RandomAccess} interface and is large, this
 * implementation dumps the specified list into an array before shuffling
 * it, and dumps the shuffled array back into the list.  This avoids the
 * quadratic behavior that would result from shuffling a "sequential
 * access" list in place.
 *
 * @param  list the list to be shuffled.
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the specified list or
 *         its list-iterator does not support the <tt>set</tt> method.
 */
public static void shuffle(List<?> list) {
    shuffle(list, r);
}
```